# What happens to at-scheduled job when PC is off?

Tags: cron, at, anacron

Say I have job scheduled via `at` - what happens when the PC is off during that scheduled time?

Will the job be caught up for during reboot? Does this have to be specified?

Or comparing this to `cron`: Is there an `anacron`-analogue for `at`?

`info at` does not seem to mention the issue.